# Are the "TCPackFrequency" and "TCPnodely" settings we use for games good for torrents?

Tags: networking, internet, bittorrent, utorrent

I wonder if they are a deterrent of good torrent networking operation.

Comment: Without context this question does not make much sence. What does "settings we use for games good for torrents" even mean?

Comment: It's not my fault you don't know of those settings. It's common knowledge among TCP gamers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generally, no.**

`TCKAckFrequency` and `TCPNoDelay`, when configured for gaming (usually the equivalent of *Every Ack* and *No Delay*) are optimizing the networking stack for lower latency at the cost of bandwidth and efficiency.

Torrenting, or any large file transfers, do not care at all about latency, and you will see a marginal benefit to overall network health if you leave them at the system defaults. However, the benefits for gaming probably far outweigh the costs to large file transfers.